# Gameobject is not showing up when built

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, blender

I have a 3D robot imported from bleder into my scene in Unity. It is fully rigged and has few animations attached to it. When playing it in Game View everything seems to work fine but, when built and run in android the 3D robot is not showing up. Got an error saying

> GPU does not support 32 bit mesh index buffers; skipped draw call

Then I unchecked Use 32-bit Display Buffer in PlayerSettings-Resolution and Presentation. It didnt solve any thing, still having the same errors.

I couldn't figure out what went wrong. I've been trying to solve it for a few hours now, [Tried this solution](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1336523/game-object-not-visible-in-apk-built.html) and few others but  non of them helped.

P.s It's not working for only my 3D robot, it works  for other Models and Gameobjects.

So, what could I possibly did wrong? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Check the shaders you use. In unity, try replacing your materials with one under the 'mobile' section and see if you see something in android. If your you shaders are the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is explicitly [called out in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rendering.IndexFormat.html). It simply means that the indices used to reference vertices in your mesh, can't be 32 bit, but should be 16 bit instead. This happens on a rare few mobile chips. This can be caused by having a mesh larger than 2^16 vertices, or by specifying the Index Format to be 32-bit in your mesh import settings.

So either change the format, or if your mesh really is too large, reduce your mesh size, or split your single large mesh up in multiple smaller meshes.

Comment: I have tried to reduce the mesh size by setting the mesh compression high, unfortunately it introduced some deformation to the object. And how do you split mesh into small meshes ? @bart